# Did we ever get to a final answer on Brewing related questions?

Tags: discussion

I know there have been a few meta discussions on brewing, specifically home brewing beer, but I don't know that those every came to a final decision.

We seem to be open to them being asked because of several brewing related tags like "bottling", so does the tag list maybe need pruning or are they just poorly defined?

I've always been of the mind to point people to the other SE site because their questions are going to hit more eyes there and they're likely to get better answers, but is that appropriate?

Comment: Mine isn't the final word by any means, but I've always thought it makes sense to point people to the site that can help them best, so yeah, keep directing to homebrew.se where you feel it fits! Regarding tags, it's probably a bit of both: they do need pruning, and are vague. In regards to subject-matter though, I think whether "bottling" would be more appropriate at homebrew.se is case-by-case. Some of these questions, I think, would be considered too "amateur" at a niche site like homebrew.se, and users may feel more welcome (and thus get more of the kind of "newbie-friendly" answers) here.

Answer (score 1):

I think there will always be room for cross-over, so there going to have to be some judgement involved.

My personal view is that home brewing questions that may have a broader, more general interest I'm happy to leave here, but more technical questions, or questions that are really only applicable to home brew I flag to move.